# How do I identify which preference panes are 32-bit and which aren't

Tags: macos, system-settings, preferences, 64-bit, 32-bit

Recently my Sound preference pane has asked me to reopen System Preferences when I select it, or when I switch away from it.

I have added a few preference panes (e.g. Wacom, an Xbox controller pane, etc).

**I'd like to know how to identify all the 32-bit vs 64-bit preference panes?**

I would like to start uninstalling the ones I don't find necessary any longer and hopefully streamline this.

Comment: Not really an answer, but might help - You can see which processes are 32-bit in Activity Monitor [Apps/Utilities], in the CPU column. You could use a process of elimination, perhaps.

Comment: @Tetsujin unfortunately only one process in Activity Monitor shows for the System Preferences, and it switches from 64 to 32 bit every time it prompts to do so.

Comment: ah, sorry. I've no idea then. Hope someone comes up with something useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Information (About this Mac - System Report) shows which are 32 and which are 64 bit. No 32-bit Preference Panes exist in my screenshot, however, as this is High Sierra.
[image]